# (Cmake-gui setup) Visual Studio is missing while specifying the generator

Tags: cmake, cmake-gui

I am using cmake-gui ,before Configuring I need to select the generator for this project,However I can't not find Visual Studio in all options ,how can I add Visual Studio for me to choose. Thanks.

Comment: Do you ever have Visual Studio installed in your system?

Comment: Do you mean Visual Studio code? If that's what you mean,the answer is yes.

Comment: No, **Visual Studio Code** is not a replacement for **Visual Studio** and cannot be used for build projects which are configured for Visual Studio. You need to install Visual Studio for use corresponding CMake generators.

Comment: Is it possible to install on Linux?

Comment: I don't know whether Visual Studio can be installed on Linux. But Linux has other good options for CMake generators, e.g `Unix Makefiles` or `Ninja`.

Comment: ok,got it !Thanks

Comment: Seems like there is CMake integration for Visual Studio Code: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/cmake-linux